# Change column visibility table pysimplegui

Tags: pysimplegui

A previous question asked about hiding a column in a pysimplegui table [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457405/can-you-add-a-hidden-value-inside-a-row-in-pysimplegui-table-object). Using the same code can I update the visible map to change the current visibility (flip them both). I changed the update line to include visible_column_map, but that fails the update (I know it doesn't really flip but just wanted quick example). Is there a way to do this or do I need two different tables?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']
data = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
    ['Harry Truman', 'May 8'],
    ['John F. Kennedy', 'May 29'],
    ['George H. W. Bush', 'June 12'],
    ['George W. Bush', 'July 6'],
    ['John Quincy Adams', 'July 11'],
    ['Garrett Walker', 'July 18'],
    ['Bill Clinton', 'August 19'],
    ['Jimmy Carter', 'October 1'],
    ['John Adams', 'October 30'],
    ['Theodore Roosevelt', 'October 27'],
    ['Frank Underwood', 'November 5'],
    ['Woodrow Wilson', 'December 28'],
]

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(("Courier New", 12))

layout = [
    [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, visible_column_map=[True, False], justification='left', select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE, enable_events=True, key='President')],
    [sg.Text('', size=(22, 1), key='Birthday')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'President':
        index = values[event][0]
        window['Birthday'].update(visible_column_map=(False, True)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option to update `visible_column_map` of `sg.Table`, and it looks you update it with wrong element `window['Birthday']` which is a `sg.Label`.

Tkinter code required here, button `Change` added to generate event to update it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']
data = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
    ['Harry Truman', 'May 8'],
    ['John F. Kennedy', 'May 29'],
    ['George H. W. Bush', 'June 12'],
    ['George W. Bush', 'July 6'],
    ['John Quincy Adams', 'July 11'],
    ['Garrett Walker', 'July 18'],
    ['Bill Clinton', 'August 19'],
    ['Jimmy Carter', 'October 1'],
    ['John Adams', 'October 30'],
    ['Theodore Roosevelt', 'October 27'],
    ['Frank Underwood', 'November 5'],
    ['Woodrow Wilson', 'December 28'],
]

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(("Courier New", 12))

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Change')],
    [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, visible_column_map=[True, False],
        justification='left', select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
        enable_events=True, metadata=False, key='President')],
    [sg.Text('', size=(22, 1), key='Birthday')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
president = window['President']

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'President':
        index = values[event][0]
        window['Birthday'].update(value=f'Birthday: {data[index][1]}')
    elif event == 'Change':
        show = president.metadata = not president.metadata
        displaycolumns = ['President', 'Date of Birth'] if show else ['President']
        president.Widget.configure(displaycolumns=displaycolumns)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking i'd have to go into TK but this is a perfect solution. Thanks again.